# Сборка dll из il кода

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток! У меня есть dll написанная на C#. Я дизассемблировал исходники этой dll с помощью ildasm.exe и получил файл с её il кодом. Затем я пытаюсь собрать этот il код обратно в dll используя ilasm.exe. Но при попытке сделать это я получаю ошибку - в консоли написано **FAILURE**, а также несколько сообщений вида **duplicate method declaration**. Причем имя метода довольно странное: ";". Я предполагаю что dll была как-то обфусцирована специально во избежание ее дизассемблирования и повторного ассемблирования. Может быть есть какие-то способы решить эту проблему и дизассемлировать dll без дублирования имен методов?

Comment: Версия .net ilasm совпадает с версией .net вашей библиотеки?

Comment: @koks_rs совпадает

Comment: Если имя метода содержит пробелы или другие странные символы, вряд ли получится так просто. (в конце-концов, если бы было просто, то методы обфускации ничего бы не стоили). Попробуйте воспользоваться каким-нибудь Mono.Cecil для переименования классов и методов.